# Smaller Notifications Tab like Stack Overflow has

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I'm trying to make a Notification system similar to Quora or Stack overflow. Whenever user clicks a button, notifications should show up in a small window no matter at which page the user is.

But I couldn't do it. Since notifications are connected to a view & a url then firstly I need to go to the url & then click on notification button, and only then the notifications show up in smaller window.

**How can I prevent myself from going to a URL connected to the view linked with Notifications & then click on notification button so that notifications will appear in smaller tab?**

Here's the url,

```
url(r'^$', views.notifs, name='notifs')
```

In View,

```
def notifs(request):
    answers = Notifs.objects.filter(user=request.user)  # not the actual method
    context = {'answers': answers}
    return render(request, 'base.html', context)
```

In between base.html I have this "Notifications" link. Note: Here I have used jQuery to load the div that will display the Notifications in smaller tab when it's clicked.

```
<a href="{% url 'notifications:notifs' %}" class="a">Notifications</a>
```

Here's that div on the same base.html page,

```
<div class="b messMess myTab" hidden="hidden">    
{% if answers %}
    {% for answer in answers %}
        Answer on{{ answer.question }}<br />
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't a python/django question, it's almost entirely about client-side scripting issue (html+javascript).

Comment: do yourself a favor and use a package like https://github.com/v1k45/django-notify-x notify. You can write it yourself as well but this requires to much knowledge about the topic...

Comment: @hansTheFranz Sir, I've tried to keep it simple & everything is working fine accept I couldn't show them up in smaller tab as described :( Is there any way?

Comment: @LieRyan Sir, How can I fix this?

Comment: Is there any universal view or something else to make this Happen?